# Open XML - Word Processing Document - Table Cell Border

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I can add a border to a table row, but how can I add a top border to a table cell? I cannot seem to find this in the ECMA documentation.

```
   TableProperties tblProperties = new TableProperties();
    TableBorders tblBorders = new TableBorders();
    TopBorder topBorder = new TopBorder();
    topBorder.Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.Thick);
    topBorder.Color = "CC0000";
    tblBorders.AppendChild(topBorder);

    tblProperties.AppendChild(tblBorders);
```

Comment: Could it be helpfull maybe [OpenXML SDK having borders for cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15791732/openxml-sdk-having-borders-for-cell)

Comment: My standard comment.  Download the OpenXML Productivity Tool from the Microsoft site.  Create a Word doc (in Word) that has a table.  Save it.  Change the table so that a table cell has a top border.  Save that file with a different name.  Open the productivity tool and use the Compare/Diff button to diff the two files.  The answer should be obvious.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Flydog57's comment to using the OpenXML Productivity Tool is the correct approach. You will spend way too much time attempting to figure things out on your own. Make a word document and then view it using the OpenXML Productivity Tool. Rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your row element.

```
 TableCellProperties tableCellProperties = new TableCellProperties();
                                        TableCellBorders tableCellBorders = new TableCellBorders();
                                        TopBorder topBorder = new TopBorder() 
                                        { 
                                          Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.CheckedBarBlack),
                                          Color = "000000"
                                        };



  tableCellBorders.AppendChild(topBorder);
                                        tableCellProperties.Append(tableCellBorders);

   rowElement.Append(tableCellProperties);
```

Attached the expected result
[image]

Answer (score 2):

And if you want to have shade on the specific row.

Kindly add the following to your row element.

```
TableCellProperties tableCellProperties = new TableCellProperties();

                                      var shading = new Shading()
                                      {
                                          Color = "auto",
                                          Fill = "D9D9D9",
                                          Val = ShadingPatternValues.Clear
                                      };
                                      tableCellProperties.Append(shading);
                                      rowElement.Append(tableCellProperties);
```

Attached the expected result.
[image]